# Why doesn't multi-langual work in the "New Item" form?

Tags: language, resource-files, multilingual

I have created a site, installed my language packs, created the term store service and created some terms in multi-language (Persian and English).

I created a resource file for list and column name.

I grabbed a resource string ($Resources:MyResource,EmployeeName;), went to the List Settings of a list, selected a column, pasted the resource string into the Column name box, and clicked OK.

The problem is : when i click new item ,the new item form show only english name for columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a name in all site's language versions. Thus switch to Persian and set a correct value. And you'll have different names for different languages.

Comment: I created 3 resource file(MyResource,MyResource.en-US,MyResource.fa-IR) . it is work for list and column name . but when i open newitem form ,this show only english.